# Can I set username and password on memcached like mysql?

Tags: php, memcached

I installed memcached and php-memcached on my ubuntu, I can connect to it by localhost on 11211 port.
I can store data in it,but I wanna set username and password on it like when I connect to database.
is it possible?how?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/SASLAuthProtocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, via SASL: http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/SASLAuthProtocol

Comment: Content is down on this link.

Answer (score 8):

`sasl_pwdb` for more simple auth deployments

`--enable-sasl-pwdb` allows memcached to use it's own password file and verify a plaintext password. The file is specified with the environment variable `MEMCACHED_SASL_PWDB`, and is a plain text file with the following syntax:

```
username:password
```

Please note that you have to specify `mech_list: plain` in your sasl config file for this to work. Ex:

```
 echo "mech_list: plain" > memcached.conf
 echo "myname:mypass" > /tmp/memcached-sasl-db
 export MEMCACHED_SASL_PWDB=/tmp/memcached-sasl-db
 export SASL_CONF_PATH=`pwd`/memcached.conf
./memcached -S -v
```

and you should be able to use your favorite memcached client with sasl support to connect to the server. (Please note that not all SASL implementations support `SASL_CB_GETCONF`, so you may have to install the sasl config (memcached.conf) to the systemwide location)

Comment: And where is that systemwide location?